Passing original public variables as parameters of method to be continually checked
I'm almost certain this question has been asked before, but probably not in the way I'm going to ask it.
I'm trying to make a simple method called DAwaiter that waits until a specific public bool variable is made true by another thread or event. I am not trying to pass a new copy of the variable into the method, I am trying to continually test the value of a specific, already-instanced variable.
I could solve this issue by making every task, such as the Home task, have its own individual copy of DAwaiter, but I'm lazy and don't want to have to update every single command individually if I can help it.
I've tried using ref bool waiter but couldn't wrap my head around how to use it effectively. I've tried using object waiter as well and am unsure why it's not working.
Here's my example:
public class MyForm : Form
{
    ArduinoComms AConnection = new ArduinoComms();

    private void homeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Run(AConnection.Home);
    }
}


public class ArduinoComms 
{
    public SerialPort Port = new SerialPort(/*parameters here*/); //creates and instances an internal serial port.

    Port.DataReceived = new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(Port_ReceivedData);

    public bool XDone, YDone, Homed, Ready, Stopped, Locked = false; //initializes a lot of bools

    string NewDataContent = "Default newDataContent - should be inaccessible. If you see this, an error has occurred.";
    

    public void Home()
    {
        Homed = false;
        Ready = false;
        XDone = false;
        YDone = false;
        Logger("Beginning home");
        //WriteMyCommand(2); sends command to arduino.
        if (!DAwaiter(Homed, true, 250)) { return; }
        
        Logger("finished home, beginning backoff");
        XDone = false;
        YDone = false;
        //WriteMyCommand(0, backoff);
        //WriteMyCommand(1, backoff);
        if (!DAwaiter(XDone && YDone, true, 250)) { return; }

        Logger("Finished home");
        Ready = true;
    }

    internal bool DAwaiter(object waiter, bool expectedValue, int delay)
    {
        bool waiterVal = (bool)waiter;

        CancellationToken ct = cts.Token;

        Logger($"{Homed}");
        Logger($"Beginning DAwaiter");
        while (waiterVal != expectedValue)
        {
            Logger($"awaiting... {waiterVal}");
            Thread.Sleep(delay);
            if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Logger($"Cancelled DAwaiter.");
                return false;
            }
            waiterVal = waiter;
        }
        Logger($"DAwaiter finished true.");
        return true;
    }

    private void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort spL = (SerialPort)sender; //instances an internal object w/ same type as the event's sender.
        byte[] buf = new byte[spL.BytesToRead]; //instantiates a buffer of appropriate length.
        spL.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length); //reads from the sender, which inherits the data from the sender, which *is* our serial port.
        NewDataContent = $"{System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf)}"; //assembles the byte array into a string.
        Logger($"Received: {NewDataContent}"); //prints the result for debug.
        string[] thingsToParse = NewDataContent.Split('\n'); //splits the string into an array along the newline in case multiple responses are sent in the same message.

        foreach (string thing in thingsToParse) //checks each newline instance individually.
        {
            switch (thing)
            {
                case string c when c.Contains("Home done"): //checks incoming data for the arduino's report phrase "Home done" when it is homed.
                    Homed = true;
                    Logger($"Homed {Homed}");
                    break;

                default: break; //do nothing
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void Logger(string message)
    {
        //log the message.
    }
}

In this example, I'm using DAwaiter to wait until the arduino on the other end of the SerialPort responds with a home signal. It registers this "home" signal by turning the public variable Homed = true . However, the DAwaiter method is only passing the starting value of Homed , which means it will never stop awaiting.

Is there a way I can make this pass the variable, so it will constantly test whether Homed == true in the if-statement in DAwaiter ?

Is this expandable to multiple variables, such as a condition where I wait for Axis1 && Axis2 == true ?


Any advice is much appreciated.

object waiter will box the bool variable, so it's now unrelated to the original bool field as its a copy...

Thank you all so much for the rapid help, you people are amazing. If there are any more issues, I'll ask for some more help. Otherwise I'll close the question.

Looking at the intent of your code, you appear to be using DAwaiter as a sort of roll your own synchronization object. It might be easier to use one of the ready-made synchronization objects like SemaphoreSlim.
I made a simulation/mock up of how you could convert the bools to semaphores and await them asynchronously. (Since you have MyForm : Form I did the example in Winforms as one might infer, but the actual semaphore code is portable).


Main Window
public partial class MyForm : Form
{
    public MyForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ArduinoComms = new ArduinoComms();
        ArduinoComms.Log += (sender, e) =>
        {
            richTextBox.AppendText($@"{DateTime.Now:hh\:mm\:ss\.ffff}: {e.Message}{Environment.NewLine}");
            richTextBox.SelectionStart = richTextBox.Text.Length;
            richTextBox.ScrollToCaret();
        };
        buttonHome.Click += async (sender, e) =>
        {
            UseWaitCursor = true;
            buttonHome.Enabled = false;
            await ArduinoComms.Home();
            buttonHome.Enabled = true;
            UseWaitCursor = false;
            // Cursor may need to be "nudged" to redraw
            Cursor.Position = new Point(Cursor.Position.X + 1, 0);
        };
    }
    ArduinoComms ArduinoComms { get; }
}


ArduinoComms Sim with Semaphores
{
    #region S I M
    class MockSerialPort
    {
        public MockSerialPort(byte[] simBuffer) => SimBuffer = simBuffer;
        public byte[] SimBuffer { get; }
    };
    #endregion S I M

    public ArduinoComms()
    {
        Port.DataReceived += Port_DataReceived;
    }

    public SerialPort Port = new SerialPort(/*parameters here*/); //creates and instances an internal serial port.

    public SemaphoreSlim XDone = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
    public SemaphoreSlim YDone = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
    public SemaphoreSlim Homed = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
    public SemaphoreSlim Ready = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
    public SemaphoreSlim Stopped = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
    public SemaphoreSlim Locked = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

    string NewDataContent = "Default newDataContent - should be inaccessible. If you see this, an error has occurred.";

    public async Task Home()
    {
        Logger($"Beginning home");
        try
        {
            // Await for any previous calls to clear
            await Homed.WaitAsync(timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            // Send command to arduino as Fire and Forget.
            _ = MockWriteMyCommand(2); 
            await Homed.WaitAsync();
        }
        finally
        {
            Homed.Release();
        }
        Logger("finished home, beginning backoff");
        try
        {
            await XDone.WaitAsync(timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            _ = MockWriteMyCommand(0, backoff: true);
            await XDone.WaitAsync();
        }
        finally
        {
            XDone.Release();
        }
        try
        {
            await YDone.WaitAsync(timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            _ = MockWriteMyCommand(1, backoff: true);
            await YDone.WaitAsync();
        }
        finally
        {
            YDone.Release();
        }
        Logger($"Finished home{Environment.NewLine}");
    }
    Random _rando = new Random(Seed: 1); // Seed is for repeatability during testing
    private async Task MockWriteMyCommand(int cmd, bool? backoff = null)
    {
        switch (cmd)
        {
            case 0:
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_rando.Next(1, 4)));
                Port_DataReceived(new MockSerialPort(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"XDone backoff={backoff}")), default);
                break;
            case 1:
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_rando.Next(1, 4)));
                Port_DataReceived(new MockSerialPort(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"YDone backoff={backoff}")), default);
                break;
            case 2:
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_rando.Next(1, 4)));
                Port_DataReceived(new MockSerialPort(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Home done")), default);
                break;
            default:
                Debug.Fail("Unrecognized command");
                break;
        }
    }

    private void Port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] buf;
        switch (sender?.GetType().Name)
        {
            case nameof(SerialPort):
                var spL = (SerialPort)sender;
                buf = new byte[spL.BytesToRead]; //instantiates a buffer of appropriate length.
                spL.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length); //reads from the sender, which inherits the data from the sender, which *is* our serial port.
                break;
            case nameof(MockSerialPort):
                var mspL = (MockSerialPort)sender;
                buf = mspL.SimBuffer;
                break;
            default: throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        NewDataContent = $"{System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf)}"; //assembles the byte array into a string.
        Logger($"Received: {NewDataContent}"); //prints the result for debug.
        string[] thingsToParse = NewDataContent.Split('\n'); //splits the string into an array along the newline in case multiple responses are sent in the same message.

        foreach (string thing in thingsToParse) //checks each newline instance individually.
        {
            switch (thing)
            {
                case string c when c.Contains("Home done"): //checks incoming data for the arduino's report phrase "Home done" when it is homed.
                    Homed.Release();
                    Logger($"Homed");
                    break;
                case string c when c.Contains("XDone"): 
                    XDone.Release();
                    Logger($"XDone");
                    break;
                case string c when c.Contains("YDone"): 
                    YDone.Release();
                    Logger($"YDone");
                    break;

                default: break; //do nothing
            }
        }
    }
    public event EventHandler<LoggerMessageArgs> Log;
    public void Logger(string message) => Log?.Invoke(this, new LoggerMessageArgs(message));
}

public class LoggerMessageArgs
{
    public LoggerMessageArgs(string message) => Message = message;

    public string Message { get; }
}



Here's the mock code I tested this answer with: Clone

Thank you so much. I've been stumbling over both this "how to wait for arduino input" issue for several months now, and the use of semaphor has finally been explained to me. Not only did you answer this question, you answered my previous 4. Looking at your solution tells me I have a lot left to learn. TYSM.

I just ran your code, for anyone else planning on trying out this example, you'll need to convert any target-typed new statements to regular statements for C# 9.0+. I.e. public SemaphoreSlim SlimShady = new(1,1); -> public SemaphoreSlim SlimShadier = new SemaphoreSlim(1,1);.

Aw heck. Those were giving you trouble? Easy fix! I changed the post and the repo so that you can pull the new commit if you want.

I hate to ask for more, but I have one more question. I noticed during your mock-homing sequence you move one axis at a time. I'm not asking you to make any new code, but is it possible to move multiple axes at the same time using this structure? (I.e. having a "waiting for XDone" and "waiting for YDone" at the same time?) I assume this would be done by separating the movement of each axis into its own task, which would be triggered at the end of the Home task. Thank you.

No prob, and I had also thought about that! So the thing is, it relies on your embedded code in the arduino. Are you spawning threads in the C code in such a way that you nudge the X and then you nudge the Y until you find the target? That would require one approach (basically setting all the semaphores, and doing an async WaitAll()). But the way I would do it is a single Seek(int X, int Y, bool homeFirst) method in the Arduino C code that does this without threading and writes that ack to the serial port when it finishes.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Analysis
Your problem as 'Ivan Petrov' mentioned is that you pass the bool value as an object then you cast it to a bool value. When you do this boxing operation, the object passed by you is transformed from a reference type into a value type. Another problem within your implementation is that even if you manage to pass the value as a reference type by using only an object, the mechanism which is used is totally unsafe. The aforementioned fact is caused by the fact that multiple threads are reading and writing from and to the same object, which can cause a Race Condition. A race condition is a OS level exception in which a memory address within the RAM memory is accessed by two or more threads simultaneously that perform a write operation. This can corrupt the data within the RAM memory.

Solution
The solution is to pass the bool value as a reference value by using the ref keyword. The ref keyword will not change the type of the bool object, but instead will pass the pointer to the value within the stack. This is thread safe because the memory address of the variable is passed between the threads. If you try to pass heap allocated objects between threads, it is recommended to use the lock statement, to fix the heap allocated address on the stack until the thread finishes its procedure with the object.
        public static void Main(){
            string thread_name = String.Empty;
            bool value = false;

            // Create and start 10 threads
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                new Thread(()=>{ThreadTask(ref thread_name, ref value);}).Start();

            // On the original thread 'lock' the string value and read both the bool and string value
            while(true){
                lock(thread_name){
                    Console.WriteLine(thread_name);
                    Console.WriteLine($"{value}\n\n");
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                }
            }
        }
        
        public static void ThreadTask(ref string thread_name, ref bool value){
            while(true){
                lock(thread_name){
                    thread_name = $"Thread Id: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}";
                    value = !value;
                }
            }
        }

